# Trying to initialize kadena token on testnet - readrow error Database error

Tags: cryptocurrency, pact, kadena

I am receiving this error when trying to initialize a token contract on kadena.

I am using free.mykeyset name in the define and enforce
keysetname in read

Calling transaction , tried using the signer "keysetname" as well as the full non k public address. I am able to deploy but cannot initialize, not sure why it seems to be a database error, nor can I find any info on "pactinternalerror"'s.

Any advice would be appreciated!

Error from (api.testnet.chainweb.com): : Failure: Database exception: {"tag":"PactInternalError","contents":"callDb (doReadRow): user error (Database error: ErrorError)"}

Answer (score 2):

You need add "create-table" function below your module and run it.

Example:
...
my module code
...

(if (read-msg "upgrade")
["upgrade"]
[
(create-table my-table)
]
)